# Getting error String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

In gridview showing date on label and fetching date from that label.

```
Datetime Date;
Label date = gvOrderExecuted.Rows[0].FindControl("lblDate") as Label;
Date = Convert.ToDateTime(date.Text);
```

This code throws an error

> 'String was not recognized as valid Date Time'.

I am passing value for date like '3/31/2015'

Comment: What is the value of `date.Text` and what is your `CurrentCulture`? Can you please debug your code and tell us?

Comment: error message is clear ... your string is not valid DATETIME

Comment: You can also try DateTime.Parse() and DateTime.TryParse() but as other commenters have said your string is invalid.

Comment: date.text value is  '3/31/2015'

Comment: @SadhanaBhort this is *not* a standard format, it's the US format. I bet your machine uses a different locale

Answer (score 4):

[`Convert.ToDateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.convert.todatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method uses [`DateTime.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.Parse.aspx) method explicitly with your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) settings if you don't provide any [`IFormatProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx).

Looks like that `M/dd/yyyy` is not a [standard date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your `CurrentCulture` and that's why it throws `FormatException`.

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.TryParseExact.aspx) methods to specify your custom string format like;

```
string s = "3/31/2015";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "M/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt); // 31/03/2015 00:00:00
}
```

[`"/"` separator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning as *replace me with current culture or supplied culture date separator.* That means, when you parse it a string with that separator, your parsing may fail *even* if your string and format matches exactly. You can escape this these character as `'/'` without worry about it.

```
string s = "3/31/2015";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "M'/'dd'/'yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: I think we should create a canned response to such questions. We keep answering the same things, never getting *all* nuances right in the first post.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Amen to that. If you have something on your mind to create a CW question about a `DateTime` parsing, I will gladly help :)